# mysql udf respond is random

Tags: c++, mysql

I call the function `AES_Dec` with the same Parameters. In most of the cases it returns the correct respond. But with a randomness of around 15% the respond is different.

```
char* AES_Dec(UDF_INIT* initid, UDF_ARGS* args, char* result, unsigned long* length, char* is_null, char* error)
{
    //initialize variables
    //initialize key
    char *keyPlain = args->args[1];
    int keylength = (static_cast<int>(args->lengths[1])) / 2;
    uint16_t *key = new uint16_t;
    hex2bin(keyPlain, reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(key));

    //output
    char *output = new char;
    bin2hex(key , keylength, output);
    *length = keylength* 2;
    return output;
}

void hex2bin(const char* src, unsigned char* target)
{
    while (*src && src[1])
    {
        *(target++) = char2int(*src) * 16 + char2int(src[1]);
        src += 2;
    }
}

int char2int(char input)
{
    if (input >= '0' && input <= '9')
        return input - '0';
    if (input >= 'A' && input <= 'F')
        return input - 'A' + 10;
    if (input >= 'a' && input <= 'f')
        return input - 'a' + 10;
    return 0;
}

void bin2hex(unsigned short* pv, size_t len, char *output)
{
    const unsigned char * buf = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(pv);
    static const char* hex_lookup = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    char *p = output;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        *p++ = hex_lookup[buf[i] >> 4];
        *p++ = hex_lookup[buf[i] & 0x0F];
    }
    *p = '\0';
}
```

I call this function with the following parameters:

```
SELECT AES_Dec('2C4E907536FBB3C9FADD4CFBD45950EF03517AA5F7F402DA9E3ABD03FC6E0068EF39F3DFC26A92B871E8D8CE521EAF6C', 'B99DD1D646CDBC8505419D069B5C0209', '1')
```

The correct respond which is returned most of the time is:

> B99DD1D646CDBC8505419D069B5C0209

And the respond which comes randomly is

> B2323332333333323333333333333332

There are only these two responses. And I have no idea why the random respond appears. In a console application it all works fine without any problems. So the code should work.

Have anyone a solution?

Thank you.

Edit: the full quellcode:

```
#include "Header.h"

#ifdef HAVE_DLOPEN

my_bool AES_Dec_init(UDF_INIT *initid, UDF_ARGS *args, char *message) {
    if (args->arg_count != 3) {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (args->arg_type[0] != STRING_RESULT ||
        args->arg_type[1] != STRING_RESULT ||
        args->arg_type[2] != STRING_RESULT) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
void AES_Dec_clear(UDF_INIT *initid, char *is_null, char *message) {
}

void AES_Dec_add(UDF_INIT *initid, UDF_ARGS *args,
    char *is_null, char *message) {
}

char* AES_Dec(UDF_INIT* initid, UDF_ARGS* args, char* result, unsigned long* length, char* is_null, char* error)
{
    //initialize variables
    //initialize modus
    char* modChar = args->args[2];
    int mod;
    if (modChar[0] == '1')
        mod = 1;
    else
        mod = 0;

    //initialize key
    char *keyPlain = args->args[1];
    int keylength = (static_cast<int>(args->lengths[1])) / 2;
    uint16_t *key = new uint16_t;
    hex2bin(keyPlain, reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(key));

    //initialize value
    const char *plain = args->args[0];
    int plainLength = 0;
    if (mod == 0)
        plainLength = args->lengths[0] / 2;
    else
        plainLength = args->lengths[0] / 2 - 16;
    uint16_t *contentWithIv = new uint16_t;
    uint16_t *iv = new uint16_t;
    hex2bin(plain, (unsigned char*)contentWithIv);
    if (mod == 1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            iv[i] = *contentWithIv;
            contentWithIv++;
        }
    }
    else
        iv == NULL;
    uint16_t *plaintext = contentWithIv;

    // Buffer for the decrypted text 
    uint16_t *decryptedtext = new uint16_t;

    int decryptedtext_len, ciphertext_len;

    // Initialise the library
    ERR_load_crypto_strings();
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    OPENSSL_config(NULL);

    // Encrypt the plaintext 
    decryptedtext_len = decrypt((unsigned char*)plaintext, plainLength, (unsigned char*)key, (unsigned char*)iv, (unsigned char*)decryptedtext, keylength * 8, mod);

    // Add a NULL terminator. We are expecting printable text 
    decryptedtext[decryptedtext_len] = '\0';

    // Clean up 
    EVP_cleanup();
    ERR_free_strings();

    char *finalDec = (char*)malloc(decryptedtext_len * 2);
    bin2hex(decryptedtext, decryptedtext_len, finalDec);

    *length = decryptedtext_len * 2;
    return finalDec; 
}

void AES_Dec_deinit(UDF_INIT *initid) {
    free(initid->ptr);
}

void handleErrors(void) {
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    abort();
}

int decrypt(unsigned char *ciphertext, int ciphertext_len, unsigned char *key, unsigned char *iv, unsigned char *plaintext, int keylength, int mod)
{
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx;

    int len;

    int plaintext_len;

    // Create and initialise the context 
    if (!(ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new())) handleErrors();

    // Initialise the decryption operation. 
    if (mod == 0) {
        if (keylength == 128)
            if (1 != EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_128_ecb(), NULL, key, NULL))
                handleErrors();
        if (keylength == 192)
            if (1 != EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_192_ecb(), NULL, key, NULL))
                handleErrors();
        if (keylength == 256)
            if (1 != EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_ecb(), NULL, key, NULL))
                handleErrors();
    }
    else if (mod == 1) {
        if (keylength == 128)
            if (1 != EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_128_cbc(), NULL, key, iv))
                handleErrors();
        if (keylength == 192)
            if (1 != EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_192_cbc(), NULL, key, iv))
                handleErrors();
        if (keylength == 256)
            if (1 != EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, key, iv))
                handleErrors();
    }
    else
        handleErrors();

    // Provide the message to be decrypted, and obtain the plaintext output.

    if (1 != EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, plaintext, &len, ciphertext, ciphertext_len))
        handleErrors();
    plaintext_len = len;

    // Finalise the decryption. 
    if (1 != EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, plaintext + len, &len)) handleErrors();
    plaintext_len += len;

    // Clean up
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);

    return plaintext_len;
}

void hex2bin(const char* src, unsigned char* target)
{
    while (*src && src[1])
    {
        *(target++) = char2int(*src) * 16 + char2int(src[1]);
        src += 2;
    }
}

int char2int(char input)
{
    if (input >= '0' && input <= '9')
        return input - '0';
    if (input >= 'A' && input <= 'F')
        return input - 'A' + 10;
    if (input >= 'a' && input <= 'f')
        return input - 'a' + 10;
    return 0;
}

void bin2hex(unsigned short* pv, size_t len, char *output)
{
    const unsigned char * buf = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(pv);
    static const char* hex_lookup = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    char *p = output;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        *p++ = hex_lookup[buf[i] >> 4];
        *p++ = hex_lookup[buf[i] & 0x0F];
    }
    *p = '\0';
}

#endif /* HAVE_DLOPEN */
```

Comment: You shouldn't be writing your own cryptographic functions. It's a horrible idea and may cause big security problems with your application. Instead use an existing trusted AES algorithm implementation such as [Brian Gladman's](https://github.com/BrianGladman/AES).

Comment: I am using the OpenSSL libary for the actual Decryption. This is only the conversion from hex string to byte and back to hex string. And it fails in this conversion and not the actual algorithm.

Comment: Could you provide a fully working example? It's hard to guess what's wrong without a good simple, working example.

Comment: I have just added the full code. I hope you can find the problem.

Comment: Let me rephrase: Could you provide a minimum amount of code that compiles and reproduces the issue?

Comment: The minimum amount of code is the first code plus the empty mysql functions.

Comment: I'm afraid I won't be able to help.

Comment: Okay. Still thank you for the help.